# How to access blob metadata using the Azure JavaScript SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

How do I read metadata for a blob in azure via the JavaScript SDK?

When I iterate the blobs returned from the specified container I see a metadata property:

[image]

But it's undefined, even though there is definitely metadata associated with the blob:

[image]

Is there something else I need to do to get the metadata to populate?

```
import { BlobServiceClient, SharedKeyCredential } from "@azure/storage-blob";

const account = "<redacted>";
const accountKey = "<redacted>";
const sharedKeyCredential = new SharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCredential);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(podcastName);

const blobs = await containerClient.listBlobsFlat({ include: ["metadata"] });
for await (const blob of blobs) {
  console.log(blob.name);
  //blob.metadata is undefined
}
```

---

```
// package.json relevant dependencies
"dependencies": {
  "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.0.0-preview.2
}
```

Comment: Can you edit you question and include the blob listing code?

Comment: @GauravMantri Sure thing :)

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it's null, then I use [getProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/bloburl?view=azure-node-latest#getproperties-aborter--iblobgetpropertiesoptions-) to get the metadata and it worked, you could have a try.

```
const containerName = "test";
const blobName = "test.txt";


let response;
let marker;

do {
    response = await containerURL.listBlobFlatSegment(aborter);
    marker = response.marker;
    for(let blob of response.segment.blobItems) {

        const url= BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL,blob.name);
        const pro=await url.getProperties(aborter);

        console.log(pro.metadata);

    }
} while (marker);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
// You can try this: 
for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
    const meta = (await blockBlobClient.getProperties()).metadata;
    console.log(meta);
    // process metadata
}
```

- I am assuming you have already declared `blockBlobClient` and `containerClient`.
- If you haven't already declared `blockBlobClient` and `containerClient` ,then you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the properties for a blob with the `getBlobMetadata` method.

```
var storage = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = storage.createBlobService();
var containerName = 'your-container-name';
var blobName = 'my-awesome-blob';
blobService.getBlobMetadata(containerName, blobName, function(err, result, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Couldn't fetch metadata for blob %s", blobName);
        console.error(err);
    } else if (!response.isSuccessful) {
        console.error("Blob %s wasn't found container %s", blobName, containerName);
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully fetched metadata for blob %s", blobName);
        console.log(result.metadata);
    }
});
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://willi.am/blog/2014/07/08/azure-blob-storage-and-node-blob-metadata/).

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this is the newer SDK. The v10 SDK I believe.

Answer (score 1):

in v12 you can retrieve metadata when listing blobs by passing the option `includeMetadata: true`

```
await containerClient.listBlobsFlat({ includeMetadata: true });
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/d2730549e078571df008e929f19c07aaf8f9efd9/sdk/storage/storage-blob/test/containerclient.spec.ts#L198